# Resolving IP address to FQDN

Tags: go, dns

I have a computer in a Windows domain and I'm trying to get the current domain name and host's FQDN from a Golang program.

The best approach that I've found is to get the IP address of all the interfaces, and try to resolve each one of them to get the FQDN. The problem is that I don't get any results after calling the function **net.LookupAddr()**, but I got the FQDN if I use the Windows command **nslookup** or the Powershell cmdlet **Resolve-DnsName**.

The following code just returns an empty array:

```
ipAddr := "10.0.100.39"
dnsName, _ := net.LookupAddr(ipAddr)
```

When if I run the nslookup or Resolve-DnsName from a powershell window, it will return the FQDN.

According to the Golang code, it should be using DNSQuery_W in Windows:
https://golang.org/src/net/lookup_windows.go#L291

[DNSQuery syscall on Go](https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go#L593)

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682016(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you know a better way to get name of the domain for the current machine in Golang, I would be happy to consider it, but still want to know what's happening here.

Comment: Isn't this just [os.Hostname](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Hostname)?

Comment: @Peter: it's a reverse dns lookup, but this looks like it should just be filed in the go issue tracker.

Comment: You typically can't resolve reserved range IPs like 10.x.x.x. They don't normally have DNS associated with them. There are exceptions like on Amazon's EC2 platform where, *if* you use their local DNS servers, you can resolve `10.in-addr.arpa`.

Comment: @tadman: most any organization of significant size will have internal DNS setup using private IP ranges. Many may not use PTR records, but it's not uncommon at all.

Comment: @JimB In order for reverse DNS to work you'll need to have PTR records and a private DNS server. I'm not sure what you mean by "not use PTR records" because that's how the `in-addr` space works.

Comment: @tadman: I mean many organization may _choose_ to not add PTR records, but it's not uncommon to have a reverse lookup zone on a private DNS server.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code (or forking it into your own code and adding logging, or whatever) to see where it's going wrong? For example, does `DnsQuery` not return anything because it's being called wrong, or does it return records but they all get filtered out because `validRecs` is doing something wrong? (Maybe something stupid, like the AD server returning the CNAME in all caps but the PTR records in lowercase; who knows…)

Comment: @abarnert no, I haven't do that, but I'll check it soon.